# How to display "Multiple" if more than one parameter value is selected or display the single value selected

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have a parameter that is multi-select. When the user selects more than one value the value "Multiple" should appear. When the user only selects one value then only that value should appear. This is for a textbox in the Header of the report.

My expression is as below:

="Division: " & IIF(Parameters!Division.Count > 1, "Multiple", Parameters!Division.Value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following expression will overcome your issue;

```
="Division: " & IIF(Parameters!Division.Count > 1, “Multiple Years”, JOIN(Parameters!Year.Value, ", "))
```